# jQuery tabs - tabs disappear on button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I implemented the `jQuery tabs` with `aspx` pages as my content instead of the `div`.

It seems working fine except when i raise an `event(button click)`. The tabs just disappears.

Here the standard code that i got from jQuery website.

```
 $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                                  "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                });
            }
        });
    });

<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Test.aspx">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="Test2.aspx">Test 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Test3.aspx">Test 2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea as to how to implement it properly.

Comment: i'm not familiar with jquery tab but, just a question, what is the purpose of the tab if you simply navigate to the target *.aspx?

Comment: the scenario was `tabs` with no `postback`. so i opted for `jquery tabs`. but then i wanted `aspx` pages to be navigated. works fine excpet when button clicks.

Comment: Made you a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FMWsU/). Update/fork it and show us what you mean with the click event.

Comment: i saw the fiddle. so it works fine even for me. but lets say `test1.aspx` has a `button` control which raises its `click event`. so when i raise the `click event` the tabs just disappear. it takes me to the `test1.aspx` page and the tabs just vanishes.

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270374/implementing-jquery-ui-1-8-2-custom-themes-in-asp-net-mvc2) may be helpful for you.

Comment: @Sandy...it wasnt really helpfull. i just want the `tabs` to work even on an `click` event on any page.

Comment: on which page are you inserting the ui tabs? Are you trying them from master page? if not master page then you will lose them if there is any postback.

Comment: I created a `Default.aspx` which just has the jQuery tabs implementation. And from here i am calling the other `aspx` pages.

Comment: I made a test with the jquery tabs. I noticed that when you specify a page as the href of the tabs, (ie. Test.aspx, Test2.aspx, etc in your case) the ui plugin will grab the target page html content and put it into your Default page, inside a div. Therefore, you page will end up having 2 form tags: the one from Test.aspx, placed inside a div, wrapped inside your Default.aspx form. So when you click on a button inside Test.aspx, the postback will go to the Test.aspx, and hence, losing your Default.aspx page altogether.

Comment: so whats the solution u suggest? should i opt for masterpage.

Comment: still waiting for some kinda solution to work upon.